# reloading table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, in-app-purchase

I've have a table view that consist of item list that depends on the item that were purchased using in app purchasing.

My question was how can I reload the tableView when the purchasing was completed/(or when new item was added on my list). The response of the storekit takes time to complete. Are there anyways to tell the app that the purchasing was completed and new item was added on my list so that I can reload my tableView.

At this time I reloading my table view by adding [myTableView reloadData] in viewWillAppear method.
But what if the user was already viewing the tableView, I can't reload the tableView because the viewWillAppear had passed.

thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get a call back when the transaction completes. Put your `reloadData` call in there.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have any idea about that.. can you try to put some sort of sample

Comment: Here are something I had: 
MainView--> tableView that contains all the purchase item... 
StoreView--> viewController for list of items available to purchase
             if I leave the StoreView at early time I had no chance to reload my tableView before the storekit update my list of items.

Comment: Read the store kit documentation. There is a list of notifications that will be sent out by the store manager when certain parts of the transaction process happen, for instance, when a new transaction starts, when one changes and when it completes, etc.